# What happens to the House card in Monopoly Deal if I lose my complete set?

Tags: monopoly-deal

In [Monopoly Deal](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/40398/monopoly-deal-card-game), if I'm forced to sell off one of my properties, and that property is part of a complete set with a House on it, what happens to the House?

I would think it should be discarded, but this came up today and I wasn't sure what the proper ruling was.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The house moves to the owner's bank.

http://monopoly.wikia.com/wiki/Monopoly_Deal

> If a property set has a House/Hotel on
> it and the property set is broken up,
> the House/Hotel is moved to the
> owner's bank, per Hasbro.

http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/375594/rules-clarification

> Hasbro wrote:
> If you break up a full
> set that has houses and hotels, those
> houses and hotels have to go into your
> bank.

Answer (score 2):

During your turn, the House can be moved to any other set.

If you don't have one, or it isn't your turn then just leave the House on the table in play for you until you are able to attach it to a set again.

Comment: That makes perfect sense; once the card has been played, there's no point in penalizing the player just because the card is not relevant for a little while (especially in a simple game like Monopoly Deal).