# Intentionally breaking up a developed monopoly

Tags: monopoly-deal

In Monopoly Deal, can you take a wild property away from a compete set with a house and hotel on it, place the house and hotel in your bank, and use the wild property towards another set?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

The rules on wilds say:

> You can swap [wilds] around amoungst different sets on your turn.

[Hasbro answered what happens to houses and hotels on a set that gets broken up](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/3418/9999):

> If you break up a full set that has houses and hotels, those houses and hotels have to go into your bank.

Thus, you can intentionally break up your own monopoly by moving the wild, in which case, the houses and hotels go to your bank.